# oracle : how to handle the scenarios where in which join doesn't matches

Tags: join

I have 2 tables `t1(id,send_date,volume)` and `t2(send_date,rate)`. I need to join these two tables and get rate from t2 when both dates are matching.

```
select t1.id, t1.volume * t2.rate 
from t1, t2 
where t1.send_date = t2.send_date
```

Now, my requirement is that when  there is no matching date in table t2 for the date in t1 and if date in t1 is SUNDAY then I need to get the rate of the next monday.

For eg: if 10th feb 2013 is not in t2 then 11th feb rate should be used for 10th feb in t1

Regards,

Sasi

Comment: Can you please mention which RDBMS you are using? SQL server? Oracle?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Its ORACLE 10g

Comment: This is a tough question. I already did +1 for that. It will take a while for me to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

The following was my query and your answer:

```
SELECT * -- Select all or any column that you want.
  FROM t2 JOIN (
  SELECT id
         , CASE
             WHEN TO_CHAR(send_date, 'DAY')
                  = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03-MAR-2013'), 'DAY')
                  -- The above condition returns true if send_date is a sunday
                  -- as '03-MAR-2013' is a sunday.
                  AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
                         FROM t2
                        WHERE t2.send_date = t1.send_date) = 0
                  -- This condition checks if any matching row exists
                  -- in t2 for the send_date.
             THEN send_date + 1  -- Increments the day by 1 to fetch
                                 -- the rates for a monday.
             Else send_date -- Leaves the send_date as it is for a normal date.
           END AS send_date
         , volume
    FROM t1
    ) USING (send_date) -- You can also use ON keyword to perform the join.
;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/edaad/9) is the SQLFiddle example for your reference.

Comment: Can somebody please format my code? I can't figure out what's gone wrong with the formatting.